# Wrapping text inside no-width container

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a flatlist component with horizontal content. The problem is the container has items with different widths depending on the image (scalable images with fixed height).
As you can see on screenshot below, text won't wrap at the end of the image. How can I fix that?

https://snack.expo.io/j9qxo4z9E

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 'min-content'` in `galleryWrapper` style.

Fork your code and do modification:

https://snack.expo.io/PZfUNBw7H

Comment: For web works like a charm, but I'm afraid there's no 'min-content' to width property on React Native. =(